# Upload New Version (Files Tab) - trigger in Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

In Lightning I am trying to write a trigger when user click "Upload New version" and try to upload. But i couldnt find tiggers to place some code before insert.
[image]In Salesforce classic, i used triggers in content version. please refer the screen shot.
[image]
Any suggestion please how to fire triggers on "upload New Version" in Salesforce Lightning or how can we get the control to write some logic when user click on "Upload New version button"?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think the same triggers on ContentVersion should work for Lightning also. Uploading a new version inserts a new record in the ContentVersion object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object underlying the lightning experience and the classic is same content version .

Looks like at this point the UI link to write triggers on content version is missing in lightning experience but that does not mean triggers wont work .

You can still code the triggers as needed using developer console or an IDE and everything should work in lightning experience .